# get input image process it and returning the output in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

my program is to get image from user,to display the image by clicking the button,to click result buttton to process the image and display it
the problem is the result image gets stored in in the folder but not displaying the image
the code is
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import cv2

def showImage():

```
    lbl1.configure(image=image_tk)
    #btn.configure(text = "load image!", command=showImage1)
```

def showImagen():

```
    img =cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV +cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
    cv2.imwrite('image1.jpeg', thresh)
    fname1 = "image1.jpeg"
    image_tkt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname1))
    btn1 = ttk.Button(c, text="result image", command=showImagenm)
   # image_tkt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="D:\project final\output1\image1.jpeg")
   # lbl2.configure(image=image_tkt)
```

def showImagenm():

```
lbl2.configure(image=image_tkt)
```

root = Tk()
c = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(5, 5, 12, 0))

c.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

d = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(5, 5, 12, 0))

d.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

fname = fd.askopenfilename()

## fname = "a.jpeg"

image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname))

## fname1 = "image1.jpeg"

## image_tkt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname1))

btn = ttk.Button(c, text="load image", command=showImage)

lbl1 = ttk.Label(c)

lbl2 = ttk.Label(d)

btn1 = ttk.Button(c, text="result image", command=showImagen)

btn.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

btn1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

lbl2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=N, pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please apply __proper code-formatting__! This will motivate readers to answer.

Comment: It is because you save the image to local variable `image_tkt` in `showImagen()` function.  The image will be destroyed upon completion of the function.  Add `global image_tkt` at the beginning of `showImagen()`.  Also you do not need to save the image to file and then load the image from file.  You can just convert the processed image `thresh` using `img = Image.fromarray(thresh)` and then `image_tkt = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`.